# UIWebView loading/randering error after resize

Tags: html, ios, css, xcode

I have a screen with 2 `UIWebView`. The user can drag the views left and right to make the right and left view bigger (respectively) and the other one smaller (like `UISplitView` but customized and self made). I'm loading .html pages from strings and local .css files. After resizing the `UIWebView` If I load a new page there will be a black or white stripe on the right side of the `UIWebView`. This stripe is part of the web view (not a space between the views), and if I scroll the `webView` up and then down, the stripe will vanish and the page will be presented correctly. This issue occurs only in iOS 6 and only on the device (on the simulator it doesn't occur).

Some notes:
- The .css file contains elements with fixed position. Changing to absolute position   didn't solve the problem but changed it: the black stripre occured during the drag.
- As slower the drag is, the stripe will be bigger.
- After resize the page is presented correctly, only when I load a new page the stripe is shown.
- The time between resizing the web view and loading a page doesn't matter, it can be straight away or after couple of minutes.

Now, as a workaround I create a new `UIWebView` and copy the old properties to the new. But than I need to reload the presented page which make a white blink...

Any idea why does it happens, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

sorry by the late feedback, but recently I was experimenting what appears to be the same problem. 
I was using an UIWebView to show some text into a grid view. The "layout" of the grid view was different from portrait to landscape, and I was working with percents of the cell to build both (landscape and portrait) grid frames, in my case it makes the web view not to have an integer size. 
It makes me thought that it can be some half-pixel issue after the web view resizing.